# Propositional Logic Valuation in SML

Tags: functional-programming, logic, sml, ml

I'm trying to define a propositional logic valuation using SML structure. A valuation in propositional logic maps named variables (i.e., strings) to Boolean values.

Here is my signature:

```
signature VALUATION =
sig
    type T
    val empty: T
    val set: T -> string -> bool -> T
    val value_of: T -> string -> bool
    val variables:  T -> string list
    val print: T -> unit
end;
```

Then I defined a matching structure:

```
structure Valuation :> VALUATION =
        struct
            type T = (string * bool) list
            val empty = []
            fun set  C a b = (a, b) :: C
            fun value_of [] x = false
                | value_of ((a,b)::d) x = if x = a then b else value_of d x  
            fun variables [] = []
                | variables ((a,b)::d) =  a::(variables d ) 
            fun print valuation = 
                (
                    List.app
                        (fn name => TextIO.print (name ^ " = " ^ Bool.toString (value_of valuation name) ^ "\n"))
                        (variables valuation);
                    TextIO.print "\n"
                )
        end;
```

So the valuations should look like `[("s",true), ("c", false), ("a", false)]`

But I can't declare like a structure valuation or make an instruction like: `[("s",true)]: Valuation.T;` When I tried to use the valuation in a function, I get errors like:

```
Can't unify (string * bool) list (*In Basis*) with
      Valuation.T
```

Could someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `Valuation.T` is opaque (hidden).
All you know about it is that it's called "T".
You can't do anything with it except through the `VALUATION` signature, and that signature makes no mention of lists.

You can only build `Valuation`s using the constructors `empty` and `set`, and you must start with `empty`.

```
- val e = Valuation.empty;
val e = - : Valuation.T
- val v = Valuation.set e "x" true;
val v = - : Valuation.T
- val v2 = Valuation.set v "y" false;
val v2 = - : Valuation.T
- Valuation.value_of v2 "x";
val it = true : bool
- Valuation.variables v2;
val it = ["y","x"] : string list
- Valuation.print v2;
y = false
x = true

val it = () : unit
```

Note that every `Valuation.T` value is printed as "-" since the internal representation isn't exposed.

Comment: Thank you very much ! ;)   . I actually implemented that through a function which create a valuation from a (string*bool) list , starting by Valuation.empty as you said.